# describe geometrically the subset of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm in complex analysis, and we were given an exercise in class, which was to describe the subset of the complex numbers geometrically.

1. I was given $|z-1|=1$
   we were to look at $z=x+yi$
2. and from that get $z-1=(x-1)+yi$
3. which was transformed into $|z-1|=\sqrt{(x-1)^{2}+y^{2}}$

I am lost at what happens between 1 & 2

Comment: Let $z=x+yi$, that's all that's happening from 1 to 2

Comment: You sure it's not a typo? Seem to me $z=x+yi$ instead of $z=xi+y$

Comment: I fixed the typo

Comment: @Andrew sotomayor. I dont understand.

Comment: You are overthinking this. It's just ordinary algebra that has little to do with complex numbers. If $a = b + c$ then $a -1 = b + c  - 1 = b-1 + c$.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments and your original context, it seems like this is what's happening. I think you're just making it more complicated than it has to be.

Let $z = x + iy$. Then $z-1 = x + iy - 1 = (x-1) + iy$. (So all you're doing is just subtracting $1$ on both sides.) Then $|z-1| = |(x-1) + iy| = \sqrt{\Re{((x-1)+iy)^2 + \Im((x-1)+iy)^2}} = \sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}$.

To describe this geometrically, $|z-1| = 1$ means a circle with a radius of $1$ has a center at the point $z=1$.

(In general, for circles in the complex plane, any $z \in \mathbb{C}$ corresponding to the points lying on the circle with a center of $z_0$ and a radius $R$ satisfy the equation $|z-z_0| = R$.)

Answer (score 0):

Since $z\in\mathbb{C}$ then there exist $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $z=x+yi$. Then:
$$z-1=x+yi-1=(x-1)+yi$$

so that $|z-1|=|(x-1)+yi|=\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}$

Further more if $|z-1|=1$, then $\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}=1$ so that, by squaring both sides:

$$(x-1)^2+y^2=1$$

which is a circle of radius $1$ with center $(1,0)$.

*A key thing to know for Complex Analysis is that since modulus means distance from the origin, then the equation $|z-a|=r$ will always represent complex numbers (points on the complex plane) that lie on the circle centered at the complex number $a$ with a radius of $r$, so that they all have the same distance, $r$, from $a$.

Comment: isn't $i^2 = -1$

Comment: Yes, but Modulus is the square root of the sum of the squares of the real and imaginary parts.